# Why is this codeigniter database return value null?

Tags: database, codeigniter, null

CodeIgniter 4, I have the following Controller code:

```
$product_tier = $this->SiteModel->getProductTierByPCUID($site->id, $p->uid);
```

with the following model code:

```
public function getProductTierByPCUID($site_id, $pcuid) {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM site_product_tier WHERE site_id = ? AND pcuid = ?';
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($site_id, $pcuid));
    return $query->getRow();
}
```

If I echo out $product_tier immediately below the call, I get this:

```
{
    "id": "256",
    "site_id": "22",
    "product": "0",
    "tier": "0"
}
```

gettype($product_tier) gives me object.

However, if I run this:

```
$used_product_tiers = array();

$product_tier = $this->SiteModel->getProductTierByPCUID($site->id, $p->uid);

if (!in_array($product_tier->id, $used_product_tiers)) {

}
```

I get the error:

```
{
    "title": "ErrorException",
    "type": "ErrorException",
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Attempt to read property \"id\" on null",
    "file": "/var/www/vhosts/dev.website.com/httpdocs/app/Controllers/Api.php",
    "line": 553,
}
```

Line 553 is the if statement.

What am I missing?

If I set product_tier->id to like 300 the code works, but it can't seem to read $product_tier->id in the if statement.

If i try to set $var = $product_tier->id; I get the same error, unless I return the value right away.

Renaming $product_tier doesn't work either.

Comment: have an `isset($product_tier->id)` check on this, `$query->getRow()` could return null if the query doesn't find a matching record. Also did you debug, as to what values are being passed to `getProductTierByPCUID()` function and whether they exist in db?